# Tulsi plant and watering it on sundays?

Tags: belief, tulasi, plants

What's the deal with no watering the plant on Sundays?

And why tulsi is sacred?

Are there other plants which are considered as sacred ones?

Comment: I have also heard somewhere that we can't light a lamp near of tulsi on sunday , but why ?

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer is as follows.

Not sure about watering the plant but plucking Tulasi leaves is prohibited on several occasions,Tithis and days including **on Sundays**.The following Sloka provides  details about  the times which are "nishiddha"(prohibited ) for plucking Tulasi leaves.

[image]

During Vyaptipata nad Vydhriti yogas,on Tuesdays,Fridays and **Sundays** (*Bhaumabhargava**bhanusu***) etc..plucking Tulasi leaves is an prohibited act.

From the [Essence of Dharma Sindhu](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php):

> Tulasi Mahima: As regards Tulasi, it is stated that during t he
>   Vaidhruti and Vyatipata times, **Sunday**-Tuesday-Fridays, Purnima and
>   Amavasyas, Sankranti days, Dwadashi Tithis and during Ashuchi days,
>   plucking Tulasi is as atrocious as cutting one’s own head.

Now coming to the question"Why Tulasi is sacred?"

The reason is well explained in [Devi Bhagavata Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/devibhagvatpurana71.html) :

> Devi Tulasi was the daughter of Dharmadvaja and she too turned out to
>   be a Tapasvini, performing extremely severe sacrifices like meditation
>   with ‘Panchagni’ or Fires on five sides of her body - on four
>   direcions and on top. Lord Brahma knew her desire of wedding Narayana
>   Himself. He explained to her that she was fully aware that She was a
>   ‘Jatismara’ ( person having  knowledge of previous birth), that she
>   was Devi Tulsi Gopi in her previous birth as a maid of Radha desirous
>   to have union with Krishna in a ‘Rasakreeda’( dance performance) which
>   was not liked by Radha who cursed her to quit but Krishna advised her
>   to take a fresh birth as the daughter of Dharmadhvaja as a Tapasvini.
>   Brahma in turn explained to Tulsi that there was a Gopa ( Cow boy)
>   named Sudama who was of Krishna’s ‘Amsa’ ( a part Extension) - also a
>   ‘Jatismara’- as he too was cursed by Devi Radha to become a demon now
>   called Sankhachooda. **After marrying him, Brahma said that she would
>   eventually attain union with Krishna as the latter would curse Tulsi
>   to become a Sacred Tree to be prayed to all over the world.**

*Are there other plants which are considered as sacred ones?*

Yes of course there are.

Like **Bilva** tree(which is dear to Goddess Lakshmi &whose leaves are very dear to Lord Shiva).**Durva**,**Aswatha** being some other examples of sacred trees.

The sacred nature of Bilwa and Aswatha can be ascertained from the verses given below:

From [Aswatha Vruksha Stotram](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Aswatha_Vruksha_Stotram),for example,:

> Moolatho Brahma roopaya, madhyatho Vishnu roopine, Agratha Shiva
>   roopaya Vruksha rajaya they nama., 1
>
> *My salutations to the king of trees. Whose root is the form of Brahma, Middle is the form of Lord Vishnu, And top is the form of Lord
>   Shiva.*

Similarly from [Bilwashtakam](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Bilwashtakam)

> Salagrama shilamekaam vipranam jatha cha arpayeth, Soma yagna maha
>   punyam, Eka bilwam shivarpanam., 4
>
> *I offer one leaf of Bilwa to Lord Shiva, For it is equal to, offering a saligrama to a Brahmin, Or the great blessing got out of performing
>   Soma Yaga,*

Answer (score 0):

> Lord Krishna told in Mahabaratha that if anybody offers a tulsi leaf and a small quantity of water he is most satisfied. That much sacred is Tulsi. In kodayin paadhai Volume 6 a tamil book by Lakshmi narasimhachariar quoted **in vaikuntam a  tulsi plant is after every 9 small flowery plants. You can water everyday. Plucking of tulsi leaves should be done by chanting kesava nama. Tell tulsi leaves that I am plucking you for the puja of Narayana**.

Keep a tulsi plant in a small cemented maadam. Apply sandal and kumkum on 4 sides. In the evening light a small lamp and keep in the space provided in the maadam. Chant tulsi gayatri mantra---  **Om tulsi Patraye vidmahe maha lakshmiyache deemehe  tanno tulasi prachodayath**

Comment: What do you mean by Keshava nama is it twelve names of Shriman Narayana? Keshava, Narayana, Madhava, Govinda, Vishnu, Madhusudana, Trivikrama, Vamana, Shridhara, Hrishikesha, Padmanabha, Damodhara.

Comment: @Yogi--Yes. Chant  om kesavaya namah while you pluck the tulsi leaf.